# Android Studio on Windows, importing and/or adding existing C++ code to a project

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, kotlin

I can't import existing C++ code into my Android project.

I'm using Android Studio, Arctic Fox, on Windows 10.   A guy sent me his Android Studio project, which includes Kotlin and C++.   I imported the project, which has C++ code in it, but for some reason the C++ code did not get included on import.  It's in the Windows directory structure, but not visible in the project and the IDE can't find it.

I've provided two images of the project tree structure inside Android Studio.  The one labeled #1 is how it should be. The one labeled #2 is how it is.  Mine is in the state of #2.

Does anyone know how I can added these files to my project?  I tried recreating a cpp folder, but could not find a way.  I was going to then recreate the cpp/h file names and add the code by cut and paste from the original project.  Although, it would be nice to just be able to import these files and folders.

The correction project configuration:

[image: The correct project configuration]

The wrong project configuration:

[image: The incorrect project configuration]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what's in that `Users` directory of yours?

Comment: @Michael That's another path to the original project.   I don't know how it was included.   Maybe Android Studio included it when I imported the project and it started building indexes, etc.      I want to remove that and add the cpp folder and files as in example #1.

Comment: Where do you go to find answers to basic questions on Android Studio?   The forums for it that I've found don't seem to be all that great.    With Visual Studio you can find multiple sources and answers for almost most questions, certainly the basic ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't install and configure the NDK for read code C++. if you want install and configure the NDK you can read this [Install and configure the NDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk)

Hope can solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.    I was able to get it working.  I was able to import the old code and sync it up with my project.   I used the project section, and in the dropdown I selected project and used the tree to get to my project where I was able to move things around and create folders.   It was all a bit awkward.